# Slow Location Tracking [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, geolocation

I am building a flutter app that should support location tracking
I noticed that google maps is very smooth at this but why the stream in the geolocator plugin is slow and how i can solve this ?

I tried to decrease the interval to 500 millieseconds but still the same problem